# Ross's Probability 10th edition Chapter 2, question 22

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am currently self-studying Sheldon Ross' Intro to Probability and I am stuck on this problem. I would appreciate any hints on how to begin with:

Each of 52 people are given a deck of cards, which they are asked to shuffle independent of each other. What is the probability that

1. the order of the cards in each shuffled deck is unique?
2. There is exactly one card that occupies the same position in the shuffled decks received from all 52 persons?
3. all cards occupy the same position in all the shuffled decks?

I appreciate any hints!

Edit: For 1. my strategy is to say that or each shuffle, there are $$52!$$ possible orderings, so there are $52!$ unique orderings where no card is fixed, $51!$ ordering where 1 card is held in the same place, and $(52-i)!$ orderings where we fix $i$ of the cards in the same place, so, there are $$\prod_{i=0}^{51}(52-i)!$$ possible unique orderings, out of $(52!)^{52}$ possible orderings, so the probability that the order of the shuffled cards is unique is
$$\frac{\prod_{i=0}^{51}(52-i)!}{(52!)^{52}}=\frac{52!}{52!}\frac{51!}{52!}\dots\frac{1!}{52!}=1\frac{1}{52}\frac{1}{52\cdot 51}\cdots\frac{1}{52\cdot 51\cdots (52-i+1)}\cdots\frac{1}{52!}$$
Which is $$\prod_{i=1}^{51}\frac{1}{52\cdots{(52-i+1)}}$$. This is the answer in the back of the book but I am unsure about the reasoning

For part b), I'm thinking, there are 52 choices for the card that occupies the same position over all decks, and there are 52 choices for the position in where it should be. Then, just like in the previous one, there are $51!$ ways to order the rest of the cards, $50!$ if we keep an additional card fixed and so on. Thus, there are $$52(52)(51!)(50!)\cdots(3!)(2!)$$ possible orderings where the one card is in the same position in all decks so the probability is

$$\frac{52(52)(51!)(50!)\cdots(3!)(2!)}{(52!)^{52}}$$

Comment: Please show your efforts. It will be much easier to help you and explain what you understand and do not understand if you show your work on the problem. Start with an easier ("smaller") problem. Suppose you have 4 people who will write a four-letter word using the letters A,B,C,D. What's the probability that they write 4 different words? Continue with the analogous versions of the other two questions.

Comment: For part $(c)$ there are $52!$ ways in which all $52$ people have the same exact arrangments of their hands. So part $(c)$ is $\frac{52!}{(52!)^{52}}$. I'm still pondering part $(b)$

Comment: Also, for part $(a)$ I'm getting $\frac{P_{52!}^{52}}{(52!)^{52}}$ since there are $52!$ choices for the first person, $52!-1$ choices for the second person, $52!-2$ choices for the third person, etc.

Comment: @MatthewPilling Thank you! I originally thought the same for part a). The book has only numerical solutions in the back and it says the solution for part a) is $\prod_{i=1}^{51}\frac{1}{52\cdots (52-i+1)}$, so I instead tried to come up with a method that gave this solution, but I do not know if they are equivalent.

Comment: @FernandoVillegasNegrete that cannot be correct. If $n=9$ then $$\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n\times (n-1) \times \dots\times(n-i+1)}=\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{P_{n}^{i}}\approx 1.68\times 10^{-29}$$ If we take $n=52$ then any calculator I've used to approximate this value gave me zero. This probability should be damn near close to $1$ since we would expect that all $52$ people would have different arrangments of their cards. What does the back of the book say for $(2)$?

Comment: @MatthewPilling You are right. I will make anote of this. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Ted Shifrin, I shall solve a more tractable problem of $4$ packs of $4$ cards distributed to $4$ people.

Each pack can be shuffled in $4!$ ways, and each of the $4$ persons can receive any one shuffle, so total ways of distribution $= (4!)^{4} = D,\;say$

**(1)** Permuting the total shuffles between the $4$ people, $\;Pr\;= \dfrac{^{4!}P_{4}}{D}$

**(2)** Choose "special" card and place in line in $4^2$ ways, $3!$ shuffles of remaining $3$ cards need to be distributed to $4$ people, thus $Pr\; = \dfrac{{4}^2\times ^{3!}P_{4}}{D}$

**(3)** Each person has the same shuffle from $4!\;$ thus $\dfrac{4!}{D}$

You should be able to easily transmute it to the required scale.